Proof of convergence in $\ell^2(\mathbb{C})$
Ive tried to find a proof for the convergence of $x+y$ in $\ell^2(\mathbb{C})$ but ive only found one for the real numbers. Given $x,y\in\ell^2(\mathbb{C})$, I want to show that $\sum_{i\geq 0} |x_i + y_i|^2 \leq \infty$. I have that $|x_i + y_i|^2\leq |x_i|^2 + |y_i|^2 + 2\operatorname{Re}(\tilde{x}_iy_i)$. I don't really know what do do with the last term. I know that $\operatorname{Re}(\tilde{x}_iy_i)\leq|x_i||y_i| =^? |x_iy_i|$. What do i do now? Can i use $|x_iy_i|\leq |x_i|^2 + |y_i|^2$. If this is the case, does it follow that $\langle x\mid y \rangle= \sum_{i\geq 0} \tilde{x}_iy_i$ always converges?

Well, if you know it for real numbers, then the inequality $$\vert x_j+y_j\vert^2\leq (\vert x_j\vert+\vert y_j\vert)^2$$ does the job (as it reduces the question to real numbers).

$|a+b|^{2}\le  2(|a|^{2}+|b|^{2})$. Your question has nothing to do with any of your tags. It is a question about complex numbers.

You seem to have answered your question on showing $\sum_{i \geq 0}\limits |x_{i} + y_{i}|^{2}$ with most of your questions. Notably, yes, the following chain of inequalities hold:
$$\Re(\overline{x}_{i} y_{i}) \leq |x_{i}| |y_{i}| = |x_{i} y_{i}| \leq |x_{i}|^{2} + |y_{i}|^{2}$$
with the last notably following from the monotonicity of the $\sqrt{}$ function.
As for your last question though, the issue here is that, unlike your previous computation, $\langle x, y \rangle$ is not necessarily real, and so bounding things using norms is not sufficient. Thus, using only the techniques from your question will not work. You also need to check the angle of the complex number sums also converges. Thus, to show that converges, it will be more useful to break things into their real and imaginary components.
